# Sort list by 2 fields - one is a text field containing numbers

Tags: apex, soql, list

I was hoping someone could help.

I'm creating the below list and trying to sort firstly by `Step_Order__c` and then by `Field_Order__c`.

```
List<Contract_Generation_Wizard__mdt> mdtList = [SELECT Id, Field_Order__c, Step_Order__c
                                                   FROM Contract_Generation_Wizard__mdt 
                                               ORDER BY Step_Order__c, Field_Order__c];
```

The issue I have is that `Field_Order__c` is a text field that contains numbers. Example values for this field include:
1.1,
2.1,
11

This means that when the list is sorted by `Field_Order__c`, 11 would come after 1.1 and before 2.1

As for the data structure of the `Contract_Generation_Wizard__mdt` object, the records would look something like this

Name = Record A, Step_Order__c = 1, Field_Order__c = 1

Name = Record B, Step_Order__c = 1, Field_Order__c = 2

Name = Record C, Step_Order__c = 1, Field_Order__c = 3

Name = Record D, Step_Order__c = 2, Field_Order__c = 1

Name = Record E, Step_Order__c = 1, Field_Order__c = 1.1

I've attached a screen shot of the query for clearer reference.
[image: Query example]
Does anybody know how I can sort the values correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The most re-usable approach is to add a formula field that converts the dotted numbers into one number e.g.:

```
formulaFieldValue = 1000000 * firstDigit + 1000 * secondDigit + thirdDigit
```

and sort by that value in queries or in default UI. There are various text functions to allow you to do that including [FIND](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5), but the formula will be [fairly messy](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/) having to deal with zero, one or two dots.

Failing that, you can do the sort in Apex by implementing [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) and so do the messy field parsing in Apex.